# How can gcc -O3 make the run so fast?

Tags: c, gcc

Let test_speed.c be the following C code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < 1000000000; i++) {}
    printf("%d", i);
}
```

I run in the terminal :

```
gcc -o test_speed test_speed.c
```

and then :

```
time ./test_speed
```

I get :

[image]

Now i run the following :

```
gcc -O3 -o test_speed test_speed.c
```

and then :

```
time ./test_speed
```

I get :

[image]

How can the second run be this fast ? Is it already computed during the compilation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gcc` "knows" that there is no body in the loop, and no dependency on any result, temporary or real -- so it *removes* the loop.

A good tool for analysis like this is [godbolt.org](http://godbolt.org) which shows you the generated assembly.  The difference between *no optimization at all* and the *`-O3` optmization* is stark:

#### No optimization

[image]

#### With -O3

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link to the tool ! If i replace 1000000000 by 10000000000 in the code (i just add a zero), then godbolt returns something very short and different. And also, the code won't stop on my machine. Is there some fixed upper bound not to exceed ?

Comment: Keep `INT_MAX` in mind and maybe try a `int64_t` or longer integer?

Comment: I would add that you don't need the extra-aggressive loop optimizations in `-O3` for this; it happens with both `-O2` and `-Os` (but not `-O1`).

Comment: Indeed, if i use the type long int for 10**10,  there is no more bug and the run is  again instantaneous for the same reason that you explained !

Comment: Note you don't need a Web service at all and can just as well run 'gcc -S' and save a couple of tons of carbon.

Answer (score 7):

that's because `-O3` aggressive optimization assumes that

```
for(i=0; i < 1000000000; i++) {}
```

has no side effect (except for the value of `i`) and removes the loop completely (directly setting `i` to `1000000000`).

Disassembly (x86):

```
00000000 <_main>:
   0:   55                      push   %ebp
   1:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
   3:   83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
   6:   83 ec 10                sub    $0x10,%esp
   9:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   e <_main+0xe>
   e:   c7 44 24 04 00 ca 9a    movl   $0x3b9aca00,0x4(%esp)  <== 1000000000 in hex, no loop
  15:   3b
  16:   c7 04 24 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,(%esp)
  1d:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   22 <_main+0x22>
  22:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  24:   c9                      leave
  25:   c3                      ret
```

that optimization level is not suitable for calibrated active-CPU loops as you can see (the result is the same with `-O2`, but the loop remains unoptimized with just `-O`)

Answer (score 2):

The compiler recognizes that the loop does nothing, and that removing it would not change the output of the program, so the loop was optimized away entirely.

Here's the assembly with `-O0`:

```asm
.L3:
    .loc 1 4 0 is_stmt 0 discriminator 3
    addl    $1, -4(%rbp)
.L2:
    .loc 1 4 0 discriminator 1
    cmpl    $999999999, -4(%rbp)        # loop 
    jle .L3 
    .loc 1 5 0 is_stmt 1
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    movl    %eax, %esi
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    printf
    movl    $0, %eax
    .loc 1 6 0
    leave   
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
```

And with `-O3`:

```asm
main:
.LFB23:
    .file 1 "x1.c"
    .loc 1 2 0
    .cfi_startproc
.LVL0:
    subq    $8, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
.LBB4:
.LBB5:
    .file 2 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h"
    .loc 2 104 0
    movl    $1000000000, %edx      # stored value, no loop
    movl    $.LC0, %esi
    movl    $1, %edi
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    call    __printf_chk
.LVL1:
.LBE5:
.LBE4:
    .loc 1 6 0
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    addq    $8, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    ret
```

You can see that in the `-O3` case the loop is removed entirely and the final value of `i`, 1000000000, is stored directly.

Answer (score 2):

A compiler only has to keep the **observable** behavior of a program. Counting a variable without any I/O, interaction, or just using its value isn't observable, so as your loop doesn't do anything, the optimizer just throws it away completely and directly assigns the final value.